# How would I achieve this "row in A * all rows in B by col in A" multiplication in NumPy without a loop?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have two matrices, A and B:

```
A = np.array([[1, 3, 2],
              [2, 2, 3],
              [3, 1, 1]])

B = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
              [1, 1, 0],
              [1, 1, 1]])
```

I want to take one column in A and multiply it by each column in B element-wise, then proceed to the next column in A. So, using just one column as an example, I will use `A[:,0]` (values 1,2,3), and multiply it by each column in B to get this:

```
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [2, 2, 0],
       [3, 3, 3]])
```

I've implemented this using `np.einsum` like so:

```
np.einsum('i,ij->ij',A[:,0],B)
```

I then want to generate a 3D matrix with the depth dimension corresponding to the multiplication by each column in A, which I implemented using a for loop:

```
np.stack([np.einsum('i,ij->ij',A[:,i],B) for i in range(0,A.shape[1])])
```

This returns my desired array:

```
array([[[0, 1, 0],
        [2, 2, 0],
        [3, 3, 3]],

       [[0, 3, 0],
        [2, 2, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 2, 0],
        [3, 3, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]]])
```

How would I go about doing this without the loop? Can this be done purely with `np.einsum`? Is there another function in NumPy that will do this more simply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this code?

```
A.T.reshape(3, 3, 1) * B
```

Reshaping ndarray can make doing many things...

Comment: Thank you, it works! So what you're doing is taking each column, putting it into the depth dimension, and then multiplying. Simple and elegant. Apologies if this was an obvious question, I am very much a beginner when it comes to matrix manipulation.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple way:

```
A.T[:,:,None]*B
```

adding the last `None` in indexing creates a new axis which is then used for broadcasting the elementwise multiplication.

Comment: Broadcasting makes my head spin. This is so elegant. I was messing around with `einsum` for a silly amount of time.

Comment: Why does the None go at the end?

Comment: It's completely equivalent to the `.reshape(3, 3, 1)` from @Gilseung Ahn (except maybe a little more efficient since it doesn't create a copy of the data)

Comment: I will have to read up more on broadcasting. This I think is even better than @Gilsueng Ahn's answer because it doesn't require passing the shape of the array. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Keeping with your usage of einsum:

```
np.einsum('ij,ik->jik', A, B)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't return the right array. Edit: thank you for fixing it, it works now. Thanks to everyone for their great help.

Comment: @Julien it was np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk', A, B) before it was edited

Comment: @Julien. It took a couple of tries to get the indices just right, and I did indeed jump the gun before that happened.